# Python Requests error 403 even with user agent

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to parse an auction website with python and request.

But so far, it's returned error 403 forbidden access cloudfare protection.

Here's bellow my code :

```
import requests
url = "https://www.interencheres.com"
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: There's a captcha there, hence the `403`.